# Ramda filter array of objects based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

I am trying to return an array of keys from a nested array based on two conditions using Ramda:

1. object has a property `delete: false`
2. object does not have property `delete`

So my array looks something like this:

```
  const array = [{id: 1, name: "test1"}, {id: 2, name: "test2", delete: true}, {id: 3, name: "test3", delete: false}]
```

So the result should be `[1, 3]`

So far I have this statement, which partially works, it returns the ids for the objects that don't have property delete, I am not sure how to check if property had delete: false and return it in the result:

```
map(
    pipe(
      ifElse(
        has("delete"),
        pipe(propEq("delete", false), prop("id")),
        prop("id")
      )
    ))(array)
```

Answer (score 3):

Reject all items with `delete: true`, and then get an array of ids using `R.pluck`:

```js
const { pipe, reject, prop, pluck } = R

const fn = pipe(
  reject(prop('delete')), // remove all items with delete: true
  pluck('id') // take the ids
)

const array = [{id: 1, name: "test1"}, {id: 2, name: "test2", delete: true}, {id: 3, name: "test3", delete: false}]

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

If you really want to be specific about the conditions, use `R.propSatisfies` with `R.either`, and use `R.equals` to specify the exact values. However, this is pretty redundant in your case:

```js
const { pipe, filter, propSatisfies, either, equals, pluck } = R

const fn = pipe(
  filter(propSatisfies(
    either(equals(false), equals(undefined)),
    'delete'
  )), // remove all items with delete: true
  pluck('id') // take the ids
)

const array = [{id: 1, name: "test1"}, {id: 2, name: "test2", delete: true}, {id: 3, name: "test3", delete: false}]

const result = fn(array)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.28.0/ramda.min.js" integrity="sha512-t0vPcE8ynwIFovsylwUuLPIbdhDj6fav2prN9fEu/VYBupsmrmk9x43Hvnt+Mgn2h5YPSJOk7PMo9zIeGedD1A==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: What if I needed to get an id from group inside the object {id: 1, name: "test1", group: {id: 45}}. I tried path but it return undefined.

Comment: Use `map(path(['group', 'id']))` instead of `pluck`.

Comment: Yep, just figured it out. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by checking for the property with the help of [`Object.hasOwn()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwn) and filtered out with the help of [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const array = [{id: 1, name: "test1"}, {id: 2, name: "test2", delete: true}, {id: 3, name: "test3", delete: false}];

const res = array.filter(obj => !Object.hasOwn(obj, 'delete') || !obj.delete).map(({ id }) => id);

console.log(res);
```